# When do Bower webjars contain source code and when do they contain the distribution file (ui-grid)

Tags: git, bower, angular-ui-grid, webjars

Just looking at Bower Webjars with a view to using the latest (3.05) version of angular-ui-grid.

There are two entries in the Bower Webjars list (http://www.webjars.org/bower) with the name "angular-ui-grid":

(i) angular-ui-grid hyperlink to https://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid covering five earlier versions. Each version just contains the distribution files (ui-grid.min.js etc.)

(ii) angular-ui-grid hyperlink to git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.git covering the most recent two releases. Each version contains the entire source code contents on git.

What I don't understand is, given that the process for adding items to webjars is so simple (click the add button, select the name and version and go) how can one person add something and the distribution files are added, but someone else goes through the same process and the source files are added?

(I presume it's something connected with what the webjars process finds in terms of config files - if I understand how this happens then I can move on to the next step of adding the dist files for the latest version)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bower WebJars contain whatever the upstream Bower distribution contains (e.g. `bower install foo`).  So minified assets are only there if the upstream provider includes them.